# How to make a phone call from react native without opening native phone dialer or asking for selection of a call app

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to call from my app. But it is opening the phone dialer.

```js
Linking.openURL(tel:${phoneNumber});
```

Comment: Linking is used to open native apps of mobile itself so it will not help you to integrate calling feature inside your app.

Comment: So what should i use?

Comment: It's not a tiny thing that can be achieved within some lines of code, you must be aware of calling features like Twilio and it will be not free.